# Zend framework 2 toroute pass variable to next controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

After a succes form i want to redirect to another controller, i do that with toRoute. Below there is an example

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('plaatsenrubriek',array('controller'=>'AdvertentieController', 'action'=>'plaatsenrubriek'));
```

Is there a way to insert a variable in the toRoute to pass to the next controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to pass a variable during a redirect would be to add a query parameter to the target route.

```
$bar = 'bar';

$this->redirect()->toRoute('myRoute', array(), array(
    'query' => array(
        'foo' => $bar,
    )
));
```

Which would result in `/myRoute?foo=bar`